# How to fix QGIS PyQGIS package?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a broken package that is preventing QGIS from loading python plugins, updating itself, or even un-installing.

The main symptom of this problem is the following message that appears when QGIS is booted:

[image: error message]

QGIS works, but none of the python plugins do and I cannot update, reinstall or uninstall QGIS. The paths of action I have tried so far are:

- Reinstall PyQGIS (which I believe to be causing the problem) using Synaptic, which leads to this error:

[image: Synaptic error message]

- Updating the packages and reinstalling, using `sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade`,

This leads to the following error:

`dpkg: error processing python-qgis (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                Errors were encountered while processing:
     python-qgis-common
     python-qgis
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

- Following advice from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1626920) on broken packages, forced install `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

The latter option flags the following error, which tells me (more or less) what the problem is, but not how to solve it:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qgis:
>    python-qgis depends on python-qgis-common (= 1.9.0+git20121201+80fa7aa~precise1); however:
>     Package python-qgis-common is not configured yet.
>   dpkg: error processing python-qgis (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    python-qgis-common
>    python-qgis

How do I solve this so I can have a fully working version of QGIS again?

Comment: Not a solution for you, but I have just hit exactly the same issue. There seems to be an error setting up the Sextante plugin on the nightly build. Setting up python-qgis-common (1.9.0+git20121201+80fa7aa~precise-ubuntugis1) ...
Compiling /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/sextante/admintools/httplib2/__init__.py ...
SyntaxError: ('from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file', ('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/sextante/admintools/httplib2/__init__.py', 26, None, 'from __future__ import generators\n')) There are work arounds that I will try to get my QGIS back up, but it looks as

Comment: Does running `sudo apt-get check` provide any more detail?

Comment: Hi RomaH, no more details, it just says:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem today, and maybe a solution that will work for you as well.

The error occurs in the file:

```
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/sextante/admintools/httplib2/__init__.py
```

(NOTE: I'm running on Linux, for me the qgis share is installed in /usr/hare, but it could be another directory for you).

As *root* or with sufficient privileges, open the file in an editor. Now move the following line:

```
from __future__ import generators
```

*above* the line starting with:

```
__author__
```

Save the file.

Now in Synaptic package manager I reinstalled python-qgis and python-qgis-common. Now the problem was solved.

I'll report this to the QGIs devs as well, but hope this helps for now.

Comment: I modified __init__.py as you suggested and that allowed python-qgis packages to be reinstalled. Great solution, so far. How did you figure that out? Had error after this: /home/robin/.qgis//python/plugins/gmap_overview_plugin/gmap_gui.py:134: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  zoom = np.abs((np.array(zooms) - scale)/scale)

Comment: Happy it worked out well. The error log pointed to the file and so I took a look at it and tried it. That worked right away :). In the QGis source code I noticed that the statement seems to be fixed already.

Comment: Great work - got my QGIS up and running again, although will stick to qgis 1.8.0~precise1 for a while now for stability. Notice the new labelling feature has not yet been incorporated in the stable release, so may go back to 1.9 at some point. Good news that the problem's been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a problem with the python-qgis-common package just try removing it with the `--purge` option and then reinstalling you might have to wrestle with dependencies, though it doesn't sound like anything that depends on it is installing.

If you ultimately cannot get it to work you might need to purge everything from your system and reinstall.  Then run `sudo apt-get remove --purge qgis` This should remove qgis, all it dependencies that are not needed elsewhere, and all configuration files except the ones in your home folder (I think, they should be at `~/.qgis` and `~/.config/QuantumGIS`).  You can also do this via Synaptic via the Removal All on your check-boxes.

This should reset everything as it was before package install.

If you installed from source, and you still have your source files you can run `make uninstall` this should do about the same as above but won't touch your dependencies or any configuration files(?).

Next time if installing from source use the [checkinstall package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) it will neatly make a *.deb file from your source and can use aptitude to manage your packages.

**Be warned I am not using 1.9